# Using two dropdown list (data on database)

Tags: php, mysql

This is the scenario: I, the admin, will be adding the chosen student to put it on the list of candidates. The process is I will be using a dropdown list.

I have two tables `tbstudent` (which is the data will be coming from). The other table is `tbposition` (Is the needed table to get and add it also on `tbcandidates`), and table `tbcandidates` (where the data will be added).

So this is the page where the admin will be picking candidate and put position
[image]

The first dropdown list is for picking a student. By just picking her name on the dropdown list all other rows of that student need to be inputted to like (student_name, student_gender, student_section). Yes, it is adding and getting all the rows by just picking her name on the dropdown list but the problem is:
[image]
Yeah, it added all the rows of chosen student but it only adding the same data which is the data on the top of the table. As you see the data on the top of the table pf `tbstudent` is Jane Rechell who is female, the other is male but when I add data of `tbstudent` on dropdown all the chosen candidate there are all getting what is on the data of the first rows which is jane rechel all of them becomes female even though their are male.

By the way, the other dropdown list is for choosing position which is retrieving from table `tbposition`

```
<?php
session_start();
require('../connection.php');
//If your session isn't valid, it returns you to the login screen for protection
 if(empty($_SESSION['admin_id'])){
 header("location:access-denied.php");
 } 
 //retrive candidates from the tbcandidates table
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbCandidates")
     or die("There are no records to display ... \n" . mysql_error()); 
 if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0){

}
?>
<?php
 // retrieving positions sql query
 $positions_retrieved=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbPositions")
 or die("There are no records to display ... \n" . mysql_error()); 
 $name_retrieved=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbstudent")

   or die("There are no records to display ... \n" . mysql_error());


 $row = mysql_fetch_array($name_retrieved);
 if($row)
 {
  //get data from db
  $name = $row['student_name'];
  $gender =$row['student_gender'];
  $grade =$row['student_grade'];
  $section =$row['candidate_section'];

  }

  ?>

 <?php
 // inserting sql query 
 if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
 {

 $newCandidateName = $_POST['name']; //prevents types of SQL injection

  $newCandidatePosition = $_POST['position']; 
  $sql = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO tbCandidates(candidate_name,candidate_gender,candidate_grade,candidate_section,candidate_position) VALUES ('$newCandidateName','$gender','$grade','$section','$newCandidatePosition')" )
    or die("Could not insert candidate at the moment". mysql_error() );

 // redirect back to candidates
  header("Location: candidates.php");
}
?>
<?php
// deleting sql query
 // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL

  if (isset($_GET['id']))
  {
  // get id value
  $id = $_GET['id'];

   // delete the entry
   $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbCandidates WHERE candidate_id='$id'")
  or die("The candidate does not exist ... \n"); 

  // redirect back to candidates
  header("Location: candidates.php");
  }
  else
  // do nothing   
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Administration Control Panel:Candidates</title>
   <link href="css/admin_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script language="JavaScript" src="js/admin.js">
   </script>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="tan">

  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="admin.php">HOME</a>
     <a href="positions.php">MANAGE POSITION</a>
     <a href="candidates.php">MANAGE CANDIDATES</a>
     <a href="refresh.php">POLL RESULTS</a>
      <a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>

 <div id="page">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>MANAGE CANDIDATES</h1>

    </div>
   <div id="container">
   <table width="380" align="center">
    <CAPTION><h3>ADD NEW CANDIDATE</h3></CAPTION>
     <form name="fmCandidates" id="fmCandidates" action="candidates.php" method="post" onsubmit="return candidateValidate(this)">
  <tr>
    <td>Candidate Name</td>
        <!--<td><input type="combobox" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/></td>-->
      <td><SELECT NAME="name" id="name">select
      <OPTION VALUE="select">select
     <?php
     //loop through all table rows
     while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($name_retrieved)){
     echo "<OPTION VALUE=$row[student_name]>$row[student_name]>$row[student_grade]";
    //mysql_free_result($positions_retrieved);
     //mysql_close($link);
     }
    ?>
     </SELECT>
     </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Candidate Position</td>
     <!--<td><input type="combobox" name="position" value="<?php echo $positions; ?>"/></td>-->     
     <td><SELECT NAME="position" id="position">select
      <OPTION VALUE="select">select
      <?php
      //loop through all table rows
      while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($positions_retrieved)){
    echo "<OPTION VALUE=$row[position_name]>$row[position_name]";
     //mysql_free_result($positions_retrieved);
     //mysql_close($link);
    }
     ?>
      </SELECT>
       </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
   <hr>
      <table border="0" width="620" align="center">
     <CAPTION><h3>AVAILABLE CANDIDATES</h3></CAPTION>
      <tr>

     <th>Candidate Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
   <th>Grade</th>
    <th>Section</th>
      <th>Candidate Position</th>
    <th>Image</th>

   </tr>
        <?php
             mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); 
   //Connect to server
          mysql_select_db("poll") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //connect to database
            $result = mysql_query("Select * from tbcandidates"); // SQL Query
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      Print "<tr>";

        Print '<td align="center">'. $row['candidate_name'] . "</td>";
         Print '<td align="center">'. $row['candidate_gender'] . "</td>";
          Print '<td align="center">'. $row['candidate_grade'] . "</td>";
         Print '<td align="center">'. $row['candidate_section'] . "</td>";

   Print '<td align="center">'. $row['candidate_position'] . "</td>";
            Print '<td><img src="date:image/jpeg;base64,' .base64_encode($row['img']).'"height="60 width="75 /></td>';
        Print '<td align="center"><a href="#" onclick="myFunction('.$row['candidate_id'].')">delete</a> </td>';

        Print '<td align="center">'. $row['available']. "</td>";

       Print "</tr>";
         }
         mysql_free_result($result);
   mysql_close($link);
       ?>
  </table>
   <script>
      function myFunction(candidate_id)
       {
       var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
       if (r==true)
         {
          window.location.assign("delete.php?id=" + candidate_id);
        }
      }
     </script>
  <hr>
   </div>
   <div id="footer"> 
   <div class="bottom_addr">



   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <style>


 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you should correct. i will tell the procedure on how to do that. hope you can do it your self.

1. First in select option use id not name in value for both dropdown
2. Then in php after form is submitted. store id in a variable and retrieve respective information using id. Now you have student info and position of respective student from dropdown. Now save info in variable like $student_grade, $student_name, $student_roll_no etc. so that you can use it to insert in a new table.
3. After doing that insert student data into new table i.e, candidate table